# mx.core::BitmapAsset could not be found

Tags: flash

I tried the code EmbedAssets.as below found in sample here:
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/

I got this error when building with mxmlc.exe and testing the ouput EmbedAssets.swf in Flash Player 9:

VerifyError: Error #1014: mx.core::BitmapAsset could not be found

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class EmbedAssets extends Sprite {

        [Embed(source="images/trophy.png")]
        private var TrophyImage:Class;

        [Embed(source="swfs/satdish.swf")]
        private var SatelliteAnimation:Class;

        public function EmbedAssets() {
            addChild(new SatelliteAnimation());
            addChild(new TrophyImage());
        }

    }
}
```

satdish.swf is not corrupted so I don't understand why this error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either modify flex-config to say

`<static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>`

or manually pass in the parameter to `mxmlc`

`mxmlc -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -debug=true Main.swf -- Main.as`

I had the same problem - [External Config file in Actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169961/external-config-file-in-actionscript-3)

Comment: Thanks. According to the [mxmlc compiler flags documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html), this is true by default. Seems that Adobe's documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

When embedding images into a class you can often get the error below:

> Exception fault: VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of z in mx.core.BitmapAsset.

To avoid this error from re-occurring you simply have to check the version of the flash player that you are running. In my case I was running flash player 9 and complying to 10 so I just point the flash player path to flash player 10 and it worked.

[Read more on my blog](http://fahimchowdhury.blogspot.com/2011/05/illegal-override-of-z-in.html).