# Definition mx.core:BitmapAsset could not be found. (with ant and FlashDevelop)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I saw this question:

[mx.core::BitmapAsset could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889171/mx-corebitmapasset-could-not-be-found)

and the answer did not help.
I am compiling the code with ant and FlashDevelop and getting the error: Definition mx.core:BitmapAsset

If I compile normally in FlashDevelop without ant it works alright(no error).
I tried doing what they suggested in the answer and some other site and it did not work.

Namely:

I changed this xml field to true:

`<static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>`

And attempted to import BitmapAsset from framework.swc

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Either link to the flex library swc, or create your own mx.core.BitmapAsset that implements all the Interfaces [BitmapAsset](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/BitmapAsset.html) implements.